# Django Add 2 Numbers and get Name and print it back in an html

Tags: python, django

I'm new to python and django
What is the correct syntax to render number and text?
I want to get the name and add 2 numbers from addition.html and print it back to results.html

I tried this code

```
def add(request):
    my_context = {
       'fname' : request.GET['first_name'],
        'val1' : int(request.GET['num1']),
        'val2' : int(request.GET['num2']),
         'res' : val1 + val2
      }
    return render(request, "result.html",my_context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Both

```
 return render(request, "result.html", my_context)
 return render(request, "result.html", {'result': res})
```

will work.
render [syntax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render):

Next you need to use the context variables in results.html

results.html  // if you used the first one otherwise only 'result' can be used in the html file

```
 {{ fname }}
val1 is  {{ val1 }}
val2 is  {{ val2 }}
result is {{ res }}
```

You can also use if ..else, iterate, filter, ... in template
[refer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/language/)

Comment: Tried it and got error. "name val1 is not defined. I also changed "=" to ":". I'm trying to render both name and val

Answer (score 0):

Solved. add variables before the context

def add(request):

```
val1 = int(request.GET['num1'])
val2 = int(request.GET['num2'])
res = val1 + val2

my_context = {
   
'fname' : (request.GET['first_name']),
'res' : res,

#return render(request, "result.html", {'result': res})
}
return render(request, "result.html",my_context)
```